# What source comments does Xcode recognize as tags?

Tags: xcode, comments

This is mostly for curiosity's sake. I've known for awhile that Xcode is capable of recognizing comments in the form of `// TODO: Something I don't feel like doing now`. Adding that line to the source of a file will cause that TODO comment to show up in Xcode's navigation bar:

[image]

I also recently discovered that comments of the form `// MARK: Something` can achieve the same effect as `#pragma mark`ing something. So I can write a comment that looks like:

```
// MARK: -
// MARK: Future Improvements:
// TODO: Make something better
// TODO: Fix some bug
```

And Xcode will render it out like this:

[image]

Which leads me to wonder: Are there other kinds of comments that Xcode can understand to improve project navigation?

Comment: You can use `// Mark: - Something` on a single line in Xcode 4

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There is also `MARK`, `FIXME`, `!!!` and `???`, e.g.

```
// FIXME: this bug needs to be fixed
```

and

```
// ???: WTF ???
```

You can see where these are defined in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/OtherFrameworks/XcodeEdit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/BaseSupport.xclangspec` (or `/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XcodeEdit.framework/Resources/BaseSupport.xclangspec` for older versions of Xcode). Presumably you could also add your own tags here if you wanted to but I have not actually tried this. Here is the relevant section in `BaseSupport.xclangspec`:

```
{
    Identifier = "xcode.lang.comment.mark";
    Syntax = {
        StartChars = "MTF!?";
        Match = (
            "^MARK:[ \t]+\(.*\)$",
            "^\(TODO:[ \t]+.*\)$",       // include "TODO: " in the markers list
            "^\(FIXME:[ \t]+.*\)$",      // include "FIXME: " in the markers list
            "^\(!!!:.*\)$",              // include "!!!:" in the markers list
            "^\(\\?\\?\\?:.*\)$"         // include "???:" in the markers list
        );
        // This is the order of captures. All of the match strings above need the same order.
        CaptureTypes = (
            "xcode.syntax.mark"
        );
        Type = "xcode.syntax.comment";
    };
},
```

These tags are also supported in the [BBEdit](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/) text editor and its freeware sibling [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/).

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to access this definitions file?

Comment: @shinnyWhack: In more recent versions of Xcode the .xclangspec files are buried within a framework inside the Xcode.app bundle.

Comment: In Swift, `???` and `!!!` do not seem to work as of Xcode 8.2.1 (they still work for Objective-C)

Comment: @JeremyP: it might be worth filing a [bug report with Apple](http://bugreporter.apple.com).

Comment: @PaulR Good idea. I never did before because, it was only when brought up on the Xcode mailing list today that I realised these markers actually existed at all (I did know about MARK and TODO)

Comment: A useful search: find /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents -name "BaseSupport.xclangspec"

Answer (score 24):

Looks like

```
// MARK:
// TODO:
// FIXME:
// ???:
// !!!:
```

all get translated into #pramga-like markers.

It appears that they stand for

```
// Mark, as in pragma
// To Do note
// Known bug marker
// Serious question about form, content, or function
// Serious concern about form, content, or function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use // MARK: - with tags below as per Apple example

```
// MARK: UICollectionViewDataSourcePrefetching

    /// - Tag: Prefetching
```